# Hypercorn - AsyncioWSGIMiddleware

Tags: python, gunicorn, uvicorn, starlette, hypercorn

I couldn't find a way to limit request body size (POST with json body) on Gunicorn/Uvicorn/Hypercorn (using Starlette), and I didn't find anything that suggests it's possible. Is it, by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

Limiting the request body size is typically done by the ASGI framework rather than the ASGI server, [as explained in the Hypercorn docs](https://pgjones.gitlab.io/hypercorn/discussion/dos_mitigations.html#large-request-body). Quart, an ASGI framework, provides this method [as discussed here](https://pgjones.gitlab.io/quart/discussion/dos_mitigations.html#large-request-body). However, Starlette, another ASGI framework, doesn't provide a method directly, [see this issue](https://github.com/encode/starlette/issues/890), instead you can use some ASGI middleware [like this one](https://github.com/steinnes/content-size-limit-asgi) to do so.